# Processing | My class isn't calling the other class

Tags: processing

```
void setup(){}
```

Honestly I have no idea what this top part does, initially my class 'Stuff' wasn't even showing up because it kept saying it does not exist, so someone did that void setup thing and it worked? I'm new to this so I apologize if I triggered someone.

```
class TarotGame1
{
  Stuff game = new Stuff();
}
```

I call the class as usual

```
class Stuff
{
```

Constructor of Stuff class

```
  Stuff()
  {
     tarotCircle(); 
     tarotCircle();
     tarotSquare();
     tarotDiamond();
     tarotPacMan();
     rngSelect1();
     rngSelect2();
     rngSelect3();
     rngSelect4();
  }

  //Tarot for Circle
  void tarotCircle()
  {
    size(800,600);
    rectMode(CENTER);

    fill(#2c3e50);
    rect(width / 2, height / 2, 300, 400, 60);
    noFill();

    fill(#16a085);
    rect(width / 2, height / 2, 250, 350, 60);
    noFill();

    fill(#c0392b);
    ellipse(width /2, 250, 100, 100);
    noFill();


    textSize(32);
    fill(#c0392b);
    text("Circle", 360, 350); 
    noFill();
  }

  //Tarot for Square

  void tarotSquare()
  {
    rectMode(CENTER);

    fill(#2c3e50);
    rect(width / 2, height / 2, 300, 400, 60);
    noFill();

    fill(#16a085);
    rect(width / 2, height / 2, 250, 350, 60);
    noFill();

    fill(#c0392b);
    rect(width / 2, 225, 100, 100);
    noFill();


    textSize(32);
    fill(#c0392b);
    text("Rectangle", 330, 350); 
    noFill();
  }

  //Tarot for Diamond

  void tarotDiamond()
  {
    rectMode(CENTER);

    fill(#8e44ad);
    rect(width / 2, height / 2, 300, 400, 60);
    noFill();

    fill(#16a085);
    rect(width / 2, height / 2, 250, 350, 60);
    noFill();

    fill(#27ae60);
    beginShape(TRIANGLE_FAN);
    vertex(57.5 + 340, 50+ 200);
    vertex(57.5+340, 15+ 200); 
    vertex(92+ 340, 50+ 200); 
    vertex(57.5+ 340, 85+ 200); 
    vertex(22+ 340, 50+ 200); 
    vertex(57.5+ 340, 15+ 200); 
    endShape();
    noFill();

    textSize(32);
    fill(#c0392b);
    text("Diamond", 330, 350); 
    noFill();
  }

  //Tarot for Pac-Man

  void tarotPacMan()
  {
    rectMode(CENTER);

    fill(#2c3e50);
    rect(width / 2, height / 2, 300, 400, 60);
    noFill();

    fill(#16a085);
    rect(width / 2, height / 2, 250, 350, 60);
    noFill();

    fill(#f1c40f);
    arc(width / 2, 250, 80, 80, 0, PI+2.5, PIE);
    noFill();

    textSize(32);
    fill(#c0392b);
    text("Pac-Man", 330, 350); 
    noFill();
  }

  //Randomized Selection #1 (Barely Randomized Values)

  void rngSelect1()
  {
    rectMode(CENTER);

    fill(#c0392b);
    size(800,600); 

    fill(#f1c40f);
    arc(500, 200, 80, 80, 0, PI+2.5, PIE);
    noFill();

    fill(#27ae60);
    beginShape(TRIANGLE_FAN);
    vertex(57.5 + 340+ 150, 50+ 200);
    vertex(57.5+340, 15+ 200); 
    vertex(92+ 340+ 150, 50+ 200); 
    vertex(57.5+ 340, 85+ 200); 
    vertex(22+ 340, 50+ 200); 
    vertex(57.5+ 340+ 150, 15+ 200); 
    endShape();
    noFill();

    fill(#8e44ad  );
    rect(width / 2, 225, 100, 100);
    noFill();

    fill(#c0392b);
    ellipse(width /2, 150, 100, 100);
    noFill();

    textSize(32);
    fill(#c0392b);
    text("Randomized Selection", 330, 500); 
    noFill();
  }

  //Randomized Selection #2 (Somewhat Randomized Values)

  void rngSelect2()
  {
    rectMode(CENTER);

    fill(#c0392b);
    size(800,600); 

    fill(#f1c40f);
    arc(500, 124, 80, 80, 0, PI+2.5, PIE);
    noFill();

    fill(#27ae60);
    beginShape(TRIANGLE_FAN);
    vertex(57.5 + 340+ 75, 50+ 200);
    vertex(57.5+340, 35+ 200); 
    vertex(92+ 340+ 57, 50+ 203); 
    vertex(57.5+ 56, 85+ 53); 
    vertex(22+ 57, 50+ 24); 
    vertex(57.5+ 75+ 150, 15+ 200); 
    endShape();
    noFill();

    fill(#8e44ad  );
    rect(width / 2, 225, 100, 100);
    noFill();

    fill(#c0392b);
    ellipse(width /2, 143, 100, 100);
    noFill();

    textSize(32);
    fill(#c0392b);
    text("Randomized Selection", 330, 500); 
    noFill();
  }

  //Randomized Selection #3 (More Randomized Values)

  void rngSelect3()
  {
    rectMode(CENTER);

    fill(#c0392b);
    size(800,600); 

    fill(#f1c40f);
    arc(500, 300, 80, 80, 0, PI+2.5, PIE);
    noFill();

    fill(#27ae60);
    beginShape(TRIANGLE_FAN);
    vertex(57.5 + 340+ 75, 50+ 23);
    vertex(57.5+340, 35+ 127); 
    vertex(92+ 340+ 57, 50+ 721); 
    vertex(57.5+ 56, 85+ 126); 
    vertex(22+ 57, 50+ 234); 
    vertex(57.5+ 75+ 150, 15+ 34); 
    endShape();
    noFill();

    fill(#8e44ad  );
    rect(111, 341, 100, 100);
    noFill();

    fill(#c0392b);
    ellipse(231, 180, 100, 100);
    noFill();

    textSize(32);
    fill(#c0392b);
    text("Randomized Selection", 330, 500); 
    noFill();
  }

  //Randomized Selection #4 (Super Randomized Values)

  void rngSelect4()
  {
    rectMode(CENTER);

    fill(#c0392b);
    size(800,600); 

    fill(#f1c40f);
    arc(500, 300, 132, 221, 0, PI+2.5, PIE);
    noFill();

    fill(#27ae60);
    beginShape(TRIANGLE_FAN);
    vertex(57.5 + 12+ 75, 50+ 23);
    vertex(57.5+340, 351+ 127); 
    vertex(92+ 340+ 577, 50+ 12); 
    vertex(57.5+ 56, 85+ 136); 
    vertex(22+ 57, 50+ 234); 
    vertex(57.5+ 75+ 150, 15+ 13); 
    endShape();
    noFill();

    fill(#8e44ad  );
    rect(123, 461, 111, 425);
    noFill();

    fill(#c0392b);
    ellipse(231, 180, 123, 560);
    noFill();

    textSize(32);
    fill(#c0392b);
    text("Randomized Selection", 310, 550); 
    noFill();
  }

}
```

Any ideas what the issue is here? If you put this in processing, I just get a blank screen.

Comment: There are certain "standard" methods (`draw()`, `setup()`, etc.) that are called at certain times in the lifecycle of the application - I'd encourage you to look up what they are and when they run.

Comment: On a similar note, I don't see where you do method calls to make your program actually *do* anything. Your `setup()` method doesn't do anything, and I don't see where you call `draw()` or anything like that. As I said above, you really, *really* need to understand what those methods do in order to successfully write a Processing program.

Comment: Ah okay! Thank you for the quick reply my friend :D

Comment: @shmosel I don't see the harm in having this tagged Java - after all, it's more or less a subset of the Java programming language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, Processing doesn't "know" to call your class methods.

Like in "standard" Java, there are certain methods with "magic" names. In Java, that method is, of course, the `main` method, which by convention is the entry point of the application.

In Processing, there are actually several methods that are analogous to this. The `setup` method that you allude to is called once at the beginning of the program. You can think of this almost like a cross between the `main` method and a class constructor in a way - you use it to do basic setup stuff (e.g. screen size, instance variables you'll use for the duration of your program, etc.).

(The difference between `setup` and `main`, of course, is that you don't need to explicitly call other lifecycle methods to make your program work).

The other important method is `void draw()`. This is automatically called several times per second by the environment. This is where you call the majority of your logic to render your screen; in particular, anything that you anticipate could regularly change should go here.

(A word of caution, though: be cautious about how much work you do in your `draw` method, since it's called so frequently - otherwise your UI will be really "laggy" and seem to hang).

There are other methods with "magic names" like this to get keyboard input, get mouse position and clicks, etc., but `void setup()` and `void draw()` are the most important.

**TL;DR** You should call the logic to render your screen in the `draw()` method so that Processing "knows" that that's what that class is for.